# apt::source definition works only with Source, not with Source.gz

Tags: repository, puppet, apt

I use this manifest:

```
apt::source { 'repo.universe-factory':
    location   => 'http://repo.universe-factory.net/debian/',
    release    => 'sid',
    repos      => 'main',
    key        => '16EF3F64CB201D9C',
    key_server => 'pgpkeys.mit.edu';
  }
```

Now I cannot install packages from it, because there exists only a `Source.gz` and not

```
http://repo.universe-factory.net/debian/dists/sid/main/source/Sources
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the missing gz ending, the problem is somewhere else:

puppet cannot follow the redirect to the https site:

```
http://repo.universe-factory.net
```

redirects to

```
https://repo.universe-factory.net
```

If you change the code to

```
apt::source { 'repo.universe-factory':
  location   => 'http://repo.universe-factory.net/debian/',
  ...
```

and ensure, that the package `apt-transport-https` is installed, it works!